# Simplify $(\log 2)^3+(\log 5)^3+(\log 2)(\log 125)$

Tags: logarithms

Can't seem to figure out how to tackle this one. I know $\log 5 = 1 - \log 2$, but I don't see a way to get around the cubed logarithms except for brute force. The answer is $1$. Using the sum of cubes formula gets me
$$
(\log 2 + 1 - \log 2)[(\log 2)^2 - \log 2(1 - \log 2) + (1 - \log 2)^2] \;,
$$ which is so complex that I feel the question isn't meant to be solved this way. Any input would be appreciated. :)

Comment: What base is $\log$? Natural logarithm? Logarithm to base 10? $\log 5 = 1-\log 2$ is only true for base 10.

Comment: Sorry. I assumed that when the base is omitted it means base 10.

Comment: @NamelessKing Look carefully. This expression is equal to $(\log2+\log5)^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your observation that $\log 5 = 1-\log 2$, along with $125 = 5^3$, we get
$$
(\log 2)^3+(\log 5)^3+(\log 2)(\log 125)\\
= (\log 2)^3 + (1-\log 2)^3 + \log2\cdot 3\log 5\\
= (\log 2)^3 + 1 - 3\log 2 + 3(\log2)^2 - (\log 2)^3 + 3\log2(1-\log 2)
$$
and we are soon left with just $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$(\log2)^3+(\log5)^3+(\log2)(\log125)\\=(\log2)^3+(\log5)^3+3(\log2)(\log5)(\log2+\log5)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \because \log2+\log5=\log10=1\\=(\log2+\log5)^3=1$

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things let $x=\log(2)$ so that $\log(5)=1-x$. Also
$$\log(125)=\log(5^3)=3\log(5)=3(1-x)$$
Now we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
(\log(2))^3+(\log(5))^3+\log(2)\log(125) & = & x^3+(1-x)^3+3x(1-x)\\
 & = & x^3+1-3x+3x^2-x^3+3x-3x^2 \\
& = & 1
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Expand $1 = (\log 2 + \log 5)^3$. Assuming base 10 here. Also note $125 = 5^3$.